# Python: manager.Queue() with asyncio. How to resolve deadlock?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, queue, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to figure out how to have a websocket based server listen to incoming requests, place them in a queue for another process to do work, then place the results in another queue where the websocket based server can wait for said result and send the response back to the client.

This is just me trying to learn and gain more experience with both asyncio and sharing data between processes. I am using Python 3.9.2 64bit.

Right now I am stuck with a deadlock as commented in the "producer_handler" function in the server code. Here is the code I am playing with:

Server:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time
from multiprocessing import Manager, Process
import websockets

logging.root.setLevel(0)



def server(recievequeue, sendqueue):


    async def consumer_handler(websocket, path):
        while True:
            logging.info('Waiting for request')
            try:
                request = await websocket.recv()
            except Exception as exception:
                logging.warning(f'consumer_handler Error: {exception}')
                break
            logging.info(f'Request: {request}')
            recievequeue.put(request)
            logging.info('Request placed in recievequeue')


    async def producer_handler(websocket, path):
        while True:
            logging.info('Waiting for response')
            response = sendqueue.get()# Deadlock is here.
            try:
                await websocket.send(response)
            except Exception as exception:
                logging.warning(f'producer_handler Error: {exception}')
                break
            logging.info('Response sent')


    async def handler(websocket, path):
        consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket, path))
        producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket, path))

        done, pending = await asyncio.wait([producer_task, consumer_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

        for task in done:
            logging.info(f'Canceling: {task}')
            task.cancel()

        for task in pending:
            logging.info(f'Canceling: {task}')
            task.cancel()


    eventloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    eventloop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8081, ssl=None))
    eventloop.run_forever()



def message_handler(recievequeue, sendqueue):
    while True:
        # I just want to test getting a message from the recievequeue, and placing it in the sendqueue
        request = recievequeue.get()
        logging.info(f'Request: {request}')
        time.sleep(3)
        data = str(time.time())
        logging.info(f'Work completed @ {data}')
        sendqueue.put(data)



def main():
    logging.info('Starting Application')

    manager = Manager()
    sendqueue = manager.Queue()
    recievequeue = manager.Queue()

    test_process_1 = Process(target=server, args=(recievequeue, sendqueue), name='Server')
    test_process_1.start()

    test_process_2 = Process(target=message_handler, args=(recievequeue, sendqueue), name='Message Handler')
    test_process_2.start()

    test_process_1.join()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the client:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import websockets

logging.root.setLevel(0)
URI = "wss://localhost:8081"



async def test():


    async def consumer_handler(connection):
        while True:
            try:
                request = await connection.recv()
            except Exception as exception:
                logging.warning(f'Error: {exception}')
                break
            logging.info(request)


    async def producer_handler(connection):
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            try:
                await connection.send('Hello World')
            except Exception as exception:
                logging.warning(f'Error: {exception}')
                break


    async with websockets.connect(URI, ssl=None) as connection:
        consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(connection))
        producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(connection))
        while True:
            await asyncio.wait([consumer_task, producer_task], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)



def main():
    logging.info('Starting Application')

    eventloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        eventloop.run_until_complete(test())
        eventloop.run_forever()
    except Exception as exception:
        logging.warning(f'Error: {exception}')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I remove the queues the server and multiple client can talk back and forth with no issues. I just can't figure out how to get() and put() the requests and responses. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to await `get` and `put`. You should also use `asyncio.sleep` rather than `time.sleep`.

Comment: If I add a slight delay (await asyncio.sleep(20)) before sendqueue.get(), I get the following error: exception=TypeError("object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression") when trying to await get and put.

Comment: Ah, sounds like you aren’t using `asyncio.Queue`. I missed that.

Comment: Is there a reason you’re mixing multiprocessing and asyncio instead of just using one?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to handle separate processes managing work while the websocket server only has to manage sending and receiving messages from and to clients. Just a personal project to better understand complex systems.

Answer (score 1):

So after looking through other posts I noticed others talking about deadlocks and using `run_in_executor`. After some more testing I found replacing the line causing the deadlock with the following code resolved the issue:

```
response = await eventloop.run_in_executor(None, sendqueue.get)
```

Comment: While `run_in_executor` will work, note that it uses threads under the hood, so you end up having _both_ threads and processes around. A possibly simpler solution is to instantiate a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and use `run_in_executor` on _that_ when you need a process to do somiething. The queueing is then implicitly handled by `concurrent.futures`, so this approach is a bit less general than spawning your own subprocess, but it's probably simpler and is directly supported by asyncio.